# CSS absolutely positioned hover

Tags: css

I have block that has transparent background, but to prevent from transparent text I position block absolutely and put it behind content block. But now i need change background on hover (all block including children). Is it possible to achieve this using only css? Also I need it to work on IE 7..

Here is example how it works.

CSS

```
.block
{
    position:relative; float:left;
}

span
{
    position:relative; float:left;
    z-index: 5;
    background-color: red;
    margin: 5px    
}

.bg
{
    background-color: blue;
    position:absolute;
    left: 0; top: 0;
    width: 100%; height: 100%;
    opacity: 0.5;
}

.bg:hover
{
    opacity: 1.0;
}
```

HTML

```
<div class="block">
    <span>this</span>
    <span>is</span>
    <span>some</span>
    <span>content</span>

    <div class="bg">
    </div>
</div
```

http://jsfiddle.net/insanebits/wHBXn/4/

EDIT:

Question : **Is it possible to achieve background color change on hover over abosolutely positioned background ?**

Comment: You can set your parent container background in rgba so you won't have to put an extra element behind it

Comment: What's your question?

Comment: @StefanV. on IE7 `rgba` is not supported

Comment: @FabrizioCalderan, filter is

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your example hover will not work when you are hovering mouse on text. You need to change background opacity when hovering on block. Here is example:

```
.block:hover .bg{
    opacity: 1.0;
}
```

Comment: This is exacly what I needed to achieve.

Answer (score 0):

you might remove the empty div and create a 24-bit `png` file with blue background and 50% opacity to put as `background-image` of your `.block` element

Then, just change the background with `.block:hover { ... }`

Comment: I think this can be achieved using javascript, and it would be faster than loading png image.. But it would be ideal to achieve it only using css

Comment: No, you just need a small (e.g. 10x10) image to repeat along x/y-axis. You may even encode it as data-uri resource and save a request... and use rgba on modern browser

Answer (score 0):

```
    .bg:hover 
{

  opacity:0.4;
filter:alpha(opacity=40);

}
```

use that option in .bg:hover..Its working in all IE browser.